Clearing screen memory
I have a screen with several dropdownbuttons on it that shows transaction data. I also use a bottom navigation bar to navigate from screens.
On initial startup of the app, I am taken to a screen where all of the active transactions are listed. If I click on one of the transactions it will open the screen with the dropdownbuttons and everything works fine. The dropdownbuttons are populated with the correct data. However, if, on my physical mobile device, I click on one of the other icons on the bottom navigation bar, for example the calendar, and then go back to the first screen but select a different transaction, the data from the first transaction shows up in the dropdownbuttons.
The textfields are fine and I think that is because I use the TexeEditorController.dispose method on them after I am finished using them.
Is there something like a dispose that I can use on the dropdownbuttons?
Thanks

Information provided is not sufficient, so I am not providing a concrete solution. But, If I had to guess, the problem may reside with Model class (class which holds some data for state management in your app) OR you can check the use of widget Keys ( keys are used to identify widgets uniquely, useful in case of stateful widgets).
